# Optimize SQL Query to achieve better Performance with more than 270 columns and 5million records includes multiple joins and Pivotting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to update a table with more than 5 million records and 270 columns. Currently the query is running for more than 20 hours. How to optimize the query

```
DECLARE @DateRange NVARCHAR(50)
SET @DateRange = ?

DECLARE @Charges TABLE 
                 (
                     EntId VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                     DateRange VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                     Identifier UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
                     Reason VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                     PriceClass VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                     AClass VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                     Bieceps VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                     abc DECIMAL(38,15) NOT NULL,
                     Rate DECIMAL(38,15) NOT NULL,
                     Total DECIMAL(38,15) NOT NULL

                     PRIMARY KEY (EntId, DateRange, Identifier, Reason, PriceClass, AClass, Bieceps)
                 );

INSERT INTO @Charges(EntId, DateRange, Identifier, Reason, PriceClass, AClass, Bieceps, abc, Rate, Total)
    SELECT 
        EntId, DateRange, Identifier, Reason, PriceClass,
        AClass, Bieceps, abc, Rate, Total
    FROM 
        zera.Charges 
    WHERE 
        DateRange = @DateRange

;WITH CostCTE AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             Bieceps, EntId, Total, r.CostColumn 
         FROM
             (SELECT 
                  DateRange, Bieceps, EntId, PriceClass, Total
              FROM 
                  [zera].[DNUC] dnc
              WHERE 
                  DateRange = @DateRange
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 
                  DateRange, duc.Bieceps, duc.EntId, PriceClass, Total
              FROM 
                  @Charges duc
              JOIN 
                  zera.Ezra pb ON pb.Identifier = duc.Identifier
              WHERE 
                  pb.ezratype <> 'qwerty'
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 
                  DateRange, pbd.Bieceps, duc.EntId, PriceClass,(Total / Equipments.cnt)
              FROM 
                  @Charges duc
              JOIN 
                  zera.Kozra pbd ON pbd.Identifier = duc.Identifier
              JOIN 
                  zera.Ezra pb ON pb.Identifier = duc.Identifier
              JOIN  
                  (SELECT  
                       COUNT(pbd.Bieceps) AS cnt, pb.Identifier AS Identifier, pb.EntId
                   FROM 
                       [zera].[Kozra] pbd
                   JOIN 
                       [zera].[Ezra] pb ON pbd.Identifier = pb.Identifier
                   WHERE  
                       pbd.StartDate <= '2019-09-31' AND pbd.EndDate >= '2019-09-01'
                       AND pb.ezratype = 'qwerty'
                   GROUP BY 
                       jaba, pb.EntId, pb.Identifier) AS Equipments ON Equipments.Identifier = duc.Identifier AND Equipments.orgUrn = duc.orgUrn
              WHERE 
                  pb.ezratype ='qwerty' AND duc.Reason  = 'Overage'
              GROUP BY 
                  DateRange, pbd.Bieceps, duc.EntId, PriceClass, Total, cnt) c
      JOIN 
          zivaTable r ON c.PriceClass = 'subru-class-'+ CAST(r.cid AS NVARCHAR(100)))tmp
    PIVOT
        (SUM(Total) FOR CostColumn 
            IN (Fee, GstFee, TotalExerciseCost, TotalTrainingCost, TotalInstrumentsCost)
        ) costs
)
,
ActivityCTE as
(
select * from(
SELECT EntId,Bieceps,r.ActivityColumn,c.ActivityAmount FROM
        (
            SELECT DateRange,Bieceps,EntId,PriceClass,1 as ActivityAmount
            FROM [zera].[DNUC] dnc
            WHERE DateRange = @DateRange
        UNION ALL
            SELECT DateRange,duc.Bieceps,duc.EntId,PriceClass,
            CASE WHEN pb.ActivityType = 'Exercise' THEN abc/1024.0 ELSE abc END AS ActivityAmount
          FROM @Charges duc
            JOIN zera.Ezra pb ON pb.Identifier = duc.Identifier
        )c
        JOIN zivaTable r ON c.PriceClass = 'subru-class-'+ CAST(r.cid AS NVARCHAR(100))
 )tmp
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(ActivityAmount) FOR ActivityColumn IN
        (
            Activity1,  Activity2,  Activity3,  Activity4,  Activity5,  Activity6,  Activity7,  Activity8,  Activity9, Activity10,
            Activity11, Activity12, Activity13, Activity14, Activity15, Activity16, Activity17, Activity18, Activity19, Activity20,
            Activity21, Activity22, Activity23, Activity24, Activity25, Activity26, Activity27, Activity28, Activity29, Activity30,
            Activity31, Activity32, Activity33, Activity34, Activity35, Activity36, Activity37, Activity38, Activity39, Activity40,
            Activity41, Activity42, Activity43, Activity44, Activity45, Activity46, Activity47, Activity48, Activity49, Activity50,
            Activity51, Activity52, Activity53, Activity54, Activity55, Activity56, Activity57, Activity58, Activity59, Activity60,
            Activity61, Activity62, Activity63, Activity64, Activity65, Activity66, Activity67, Activity68, Activity69, Activity70,
            Activity71, Activity72, Activity73, Activity74, Activity75, Activity76, Activity77, Activity78, Activity79, Activity80,
          Activity81, Activity82, Activity83, Activity84,   Activity85, Activity86, Activity87, Activity88, Activity89, Activity90,
     Activity91, Activity92, Activity93, Activity94, Activity95, Activity96, Activity97, Activity98, Activity99, Activity100,
     Activity101, Activity102, Activity103, Activity104, Activity105, Activity106, Activity107, Activity108, Activity109, Activity110,
     Activity111, Activity112, Activity113, Activity114, Activity115, Activity116, Activity117, Activity118, Activity119, Activity120,
     Activity121, Activity122, Activity123, Activity124, Activity125, Activity126, Activity127, Activity128, Activity129, Activity130,
     Activity131, Activity132, Activity133, Activity134, Activity135, Activity136, Activity137, Activity138, Activity139, Activity140,
     Activity141, Activity142, Activity143, Activity144, Activity145, Activity146, Activity147, Activity148, Activity149, Activity150,
     Activity151, Activity152, Activity153, Activity154, Activity155, Activity156, Activity157, Activity158, Activity159, Activity160,
     Activity161, Activity162, Activity163, Activity164, Activity165, Activity166, Activity167, Activity168, Activity169, Activity170,
     Activity171, Activity172, Activity173, Activity174, Activity175, Activity176, Activity177, Activity178, Activity179, Activity180,
     Activity181, Activity182, Activity183, Activity184, Activity185, Activity186, Activity187, Activity188, Activity189, Activity190,
     Activity191, Activity192, Activity193, Activity194, Activity195, Activity196, Activity197, Activity198, Activity199, Activity200,
     Activity201, Activity202, Activity203, Activity204, Activity205, Activity206, Activity207, Activity208, Activity209, Activity210,
     Activity211, Activity212, Activity213, Activity214, Activity215, Activity216, Activity217, Activity218, Activity219, Activity220,
     Activity221, Activity222, Activity223, Activity224, Activity225, Activity226, Activity227, Activity228, Activity229, Activity230
        )
    ) Activitys
)
UPDATE ssc SET
 ssc.Fee = ISNULL(CostCTE.Fee,0),
    ssc.GstFee=  ISNULL(CostCTE.GstFee, 0),
 ssc.TotalExerciseCost = ISNULL(CostCTE.TotalExerciseCost, 0),
    ssc.TotalTrainingCost =ISNULL(CostCTE.TotalTrainingCost, 0),
    ssc.TotalInstrumentsCost = ISNULL(CostCTE.TotalInstrumentsCost, 0),
 ssc.ExerciseplanOverage = ISNULL(ssc.ExerciseplanOverage,0),
 ssc.TrainingPlanOverage = ISNULL(ssc.TrainingPlanOverage,0),
    ssc.Activity1 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity1, 0), ssc.Activity2 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity2, 0), ssc.Activity3 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity3, 0), ssc.Activity4 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity4, 0), ssc.Activity5 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity5, 0),
    ssc.Activity6 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity6, 0), ssc.Activity7 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity7, 0), ssc.Activity8 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity8, 0), ssc.Activity9 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity9, 0), ssc.Activity10 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity10, 0),
    ssc.Activity11 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity11, 0), ssc.Activity12 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity12, 0), ssc.Activity13 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity13, 0), ssc.Activity14 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity14, 0), ssc.Activity15 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity15, 0),
    ssc.Activity16 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity16, 0), ssc.Activity17 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity17, 0), ssc.Activity18 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity18, 0), ssc.Activity19 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity19, 0), ssc.Activity20 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity20, 0),
    ssc.Activity21 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity21, 0), ssc.Activity22 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity22, 0), ssc.Activity23 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity23, 0), ssc.Activity24 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity24, 0), ssc.Activity25 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity25, 0),
    ssc.Activity26 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity26, 0), ssc.Activity27 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity27, 0), ssc.Activity28 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity28, 0), ssc.Activity29 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity29, 0), ssc.Activity30 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity30, 0),
    ssc.Activity31 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity31, 0), ssc.Activity32 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity32, 0), ssc.Activity33 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity33, 0), ssc.Activity34 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity34, 0), ssc.Activity35 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity35, 0),
    ssc.Activity36 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity36, 0), ssc.Activity37 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity37, 0), ssc.Activity38 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity38, 0), ssc.Activity39 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity39, 0), ssc.Activity40 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity40, 0),
    ssc.Activity41 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity41, 0), ssc.Activity42 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity42, 0), ssc.Activity43 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity43, 0), ssc.Activity44 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity44, 0), ssc.Activity45 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity45, 0),
    ssc.Activity46 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity46, 0), ssc.Activity47 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity47, 0), ssc.Activity48 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity48, 0), ssc.Activity49 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity49, 0), ssc.Activity50 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity50, 0),
    ssc.Activity51 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity51, 0), ssc.Activity52 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity52, 0), ssc.Activity53 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity53, 0), ssc.Activity54 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity54, 0), ssc.Activity55 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity55, 0),
    ssc.Activity56 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity56, 0), ssc.Activity57 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity57, 0), ssc.Activity58 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity58, 0), ssc.Activity59 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity59, 0), ssc.Activity60 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity60, 0),
    ssc.Activity61 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity61, 0), ssc.Activity62 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity62, 0), ssc.Activity63 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity63, 0), ssc.Activity64 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity64, 0), ssc.Activity65 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity65, 0),
    ssc.Activity66 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity66, 0), ssc.Activity67 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity67, 0), ssc.Activity68 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity68, 0), ssc.Activity69 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity69, 0), ssc.Activity70 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity70, 0),
    ssc.Activity71 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity71, 0), ssc.Activity72 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity72, 0), ssc.Activity73 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity73, 0), ssc.Activity74 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity74, 0), ssc.Activity75 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity75, 0),
    ssc.Activity76 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity76, 0), ssc.Activity77 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity77, 0), ssc.Activity78 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity78, 0), ssc.Activity79 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity79, 0), ssc.Activity80 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity80, 0),
    ssc.Activity81 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity81, 0), ssc.Activity82 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity82, 0), ssc.Activity83 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity83, 0), ssc.Activity84 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity84, 0), ssc.Activity85 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity85, 0),
    ssc.Activity86 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity86, 0), ssc.Activity87 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity87, 0), ssc.Activity88 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity88, 0), ssc.Activity89 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity89, 0), ssc.Activity90 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity90, 0),
 ssc.Activity91 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity91, 0), ssc.Activity92 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity92, 0), ssc.Activity93 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity93, 0), ssc.Activity94 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity94, 0), ssc.Activity95 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity95, 0),
    ssc.Activity96 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity96, 0), ssc.Activity97 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity97, 0), ssc.Activity98 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity98, 0), ssc.Activity99 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity99, 0), ssc.Activity100 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity100, 0),
 ssc.Activity101 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity101, 0), ssc.Activity102 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity102, 0), ssc.Activity103 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity103, 0), ssc.Activity104 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity104, 0), ssc.Activity105 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity105, 0),
    ssc.Activity106 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity106, 0), ssc.Activity107 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity107, 0), ssc.Activity108 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity108, 0), ssc.Activity109 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity109, 0), ssc.Activity110 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity110, 0),
 ssc.Activity111 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity111, 0), ssc.Activity112 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity112, 0), ssc.Activity113 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity113, 0), ssc.Activity114 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity114, 0), ssc.Activity115 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity115, 0),
    ssc.Activity116 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity116, 0), ssc.Activity117 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity117, 0), ssc.Activity118 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity118, 0), ssc.Activity119 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity119, 0), ssc.Activity120 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity120, 0),
 ssc.Activity121 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity121, 0), ssc.Activity122 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity122, 0), ssc.Activity123 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity123, 0), ssc.Activity124 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity124, 0), ssc.Activity125 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity125, 0),
    ssc.Activity126 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity126, 0), ssc.Activity127 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity127, 0), ssc.Activity128 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity128, 0), ssc.Activity129 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity129, 0), ssc.Activity130 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity130, 0),
 ssc.Activity131 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity131, 0), ssc.Activity132 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity132, 0), ssc.Activity133 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity133, 0), ssc.Activity134 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity134, 0), ssc.Activity135 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity135, 0),
    ssc.Activity136 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity136, 0), ssc.Activity137 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity137, 0), ssc.Activity138 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity138, 0), ssc.Activity139 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity139, 0), ssc.Activity140 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity140, 0),
 ssc.Activity141 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity141, 0), ssc.Activity142 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity142, 0), ssc.Activity143 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity143, 0), ssc.Activity144 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity144, 0), ssc.Activity145 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity145, 0),
    ssc.Activity146 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity146, 0), ssc.Activity147 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity147, 0), ssc.Activity148 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity148, 0), ssc.Activity149 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity149, 0), ssc.Activity150 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity150, 0),
 ssc.Activity151 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity151, 0), ssc.Activity152 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity152, 0), ssc.Activity153 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity153, 0), ssc.Activity154 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity154, 0), ssc.Activity155 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity155, 0),
    ssc.Activity156 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity156, 0), ssc.Activity157 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity157, 0), ssc.Activity158 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity158, 0), ssc.Activity159 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity159, 0), ssc.Activity160 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity160, 0),
 ssc.Activity161 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity161, 0), ssc.Activity162 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity162, 0), ssc.Activity163 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity163, 0), ssc.Activity164 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity164, 0), ssc.Activity165 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity165, 0),
    ssc.Activity166 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity166, 0), ssc.Activity167 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity167, 0), ssc.Activity168 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity168, 0), ssc.Activity169 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity169, 0), ssc.Activity170 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity170, 0),
 ssc.Activity171 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity171, 0), ssc.Activity172 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity172, 0), ssc.Activity173 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity173, 0), ssc.Activity174 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity174, 0), ssc.Activity175 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity175, 0),
    ssc.Activity176 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity176, 0), ssc.Activity177 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity177, 0), ssc.Activity178 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity178, 0), ssc.Activity179 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity179, 0), ssc.Activity180 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity180, 0),
 ssc.Activity181 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity181, 0), ssc.Activity182 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity182, 0), ssc.Activity183 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity183, 0), ssc.Activity184 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity184, 0), ssc.Activity185 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity185, 0),
    ssc.Activity186 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity186, 0), ssc.Activity187 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity187, 0), ssc.Activity188 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity188, 0), ssc.Activity189 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity189, 0), ssc.Activity190 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity190, 0),
 ssc.Activity191 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity191, 0), ssc.Activity192 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity192, 0), ssc.Activity193 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity193, 0), ssc.Activity194 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity194, 0), ssc.Activity195 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity195, 0),
    ssc.Activity196 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity196, 0), ssc.Activity197 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity197, 0), ssc.Activity198 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity198, 0), ssc.Activity199 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity199, 0), ssc.Activity200 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity200, 0),
 ssc.Activity201 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity201, 0), ssc.Activity202 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity202, 0), ssc.Activity203 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity203, 0), ssc.Activity204 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity204, 0), ssc.Activity205 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity205, 0),
    ssc.Activity206 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity206, 0), ssc.Activity207 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity207, 0), ssc.Activity208 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity208, 0), ssc.Activity209 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity209, 0), ssc.Activity210 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity210, 0),
 ssc.Activity211 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity211, 0), ssc.Activity212 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity212, 0), ssc.Activity213 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity213, 0), ssc.Activity214 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity214, 0), ssc.Activity215 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity215, 0),
    ssc.Activity216 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity216, 0), ssc.Activity217 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity217, 0), ssc.Activity218 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity218, 0), ssc.Activity219 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity219, 0), ssc.Activity220 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity220, 0),
 ssc.Activity221 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity221, 0), ssc.Activity222 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity222, 0), ssc.Activity223 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity223, 0), ssc.Activity224 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity224, 0), ssc.Activity225 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity225, 0),
    ssc.Activity226 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity226, 0), ssc.Activity227 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity227, 0), ssc.Activity228 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity228, 0), ssc.Activity229 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity229, 0), ssc.Activity230 = ISNULL(ActivityCTE.Activity230, 0)
 FROM zeraT.MainTable ssc
LEFT OUTER JOIN CostCTE on CostCTE.EntId = ssc.EntId and CostCTE.Bieceps = ssc.Bieceps
LEFT OUTER JOIN ActivityCTE ON ssc.EntId = ActivityCTE.EntId and ssc.Bieceps = ActivityCTE.Bieceps
```

Comment: I think you need to break this down and find out where the bulk of the time is being spent. Maybe break it up into multiple temp tables so you can find out which part you need to look at. It should be representative if you base it on the first 100,000 rows for testing.

Comment: @benjamin-moskovits Can you please look into this query?

Comment: The very first thing I would do would be to change @Charges (table variable)  into #Charges (temp table)... the use of a table variable prevents the query going parallel and see what that does for you

Then (as TomC says) I'd look at breaking the query up, for example, materialising some of those CTEs and that pivot into  #temp tables

Comment: @uberbloke Iam calling this query to execute inside spark. Am getting error while using Temp table. That is why I changed to use a table variable